# Create a 16.04 KVM guest on 14.04

Tags: 16.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vmbuilder

I have a 14.04 host running a bunch of 14.04 guest VM's with KVM. I've used `vmbuilder` to build these guests.

I'd like to also create a 16.04 guest VM on this host. But I see that `xenial` is not a valid suite option for `vmbuilder`.

- Is it possible to create a `xenial` guest with vmbuilder?
- If not, is it possible to create it with other tools and host it on 14.04?
- If so, how do I do this?

Comment: Consider using Virtual Box

Comment: @pfeiffep I suppose that is an option down the road, but there's some infrastructure that I'm dealing with and I can't just switch gears like that.

Comment: You may create kvm guest with virsh (see manpages) or in a GUI with virt-manager if you have downloaded the installation ISO for the guest system

Answer (score 0):

I can not answer the question about vmbuilder, because I have never used it.

I would download the iso file for whatever Ubutnu 16.04 you want to use and then do, for example, this, from the same directory as the iso file:

```
sudo virt-install -n desk_dev -r 8192 --disk path=/media/newhd/desk_dev.img,bus=virtio,size=50 -c xenial-desktop-amd64-20160320.iso --network bridge=br0,model=virtio,mac=52:54:00:87:d2:f4 --video=vmvga --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole -v --vcpus=4
```

Where I am naming the VM `desk-dev`, and giving it 8 gigabytes of memory, and putting the image file at `/media/newhd/desk_dev.img` with a size of 50 gigabytes, and use whatever I named the iso file as, in this case `xenial-desktop-amd64-20160320.iso`, with a bridged network. I assign the MAC address because I already have entries in my DHCP and DNS servers for such a VM. I use the vmvga driver because the default one sucks. I use VNC to communicate with the VM, you might want different. I give it 4 CPUs.